Get all the items in the list that are not found in the table
SELECT username
FROM (VALUES("user1"),("user2"),("user3")) V(username)
EXCEPT
SELECT username
FROM userdetails;

In the query above, in Cassandra it doesn't work, and I get the following error:

SyntaxException: line 2:5 no viable alternative at input '(' (SELECT usernameFROM [(]...)

I tried researching, but nothing was found for a solution in Cassandra.

CQL which is Cassandra's query language (1) only has a subset of the SQL grammar and (2) does not include the EXCEPT clause. This is intentional because Cassandra is designed for extremely fast data retrieval at internet scale so reads are optimised for single-partition requests.
You choose Cassandra because you have a scale problem and need to retrieve data in single-millisecond latency.
In your case, you are performing a full table scan with SELECT username FROM userdetails -- an unbounded, unfiltered query. If you think about it, this query does not scale.
Consider use cases with billions and billions of records (partitions) in a table that is distributed across hundreds of nodes in the cluster. If we allow an unbounded query to run, there is a good chance that it will never complete within an "acceptable" timeframe.
Cassandra is optimised for OLTP workloads. When you need to run analytics (or analytics-like) workloads then consider using Apache Spark to execute the analytics queries. These are executed using the Spark Cassandra connector which optimises the query by breaking it up into small token ranges then distributes them across workers/executors which in turn request the sub-range reads from replica nodes in the Cassandra cluster. Cheers!

It is for a registration screen where user will type in a username for their profile and it will recommend suggestions, but those suggestions list needs to be validated across Cassandra database to make sure that username string is not already taken.

How would I take a list of username string [ "user1", "user2", "user3"] and validate across cassandra table "userdetails" which has a "username" column?

A friendly request that you create a new post since that is a slightly different question to the one you asked above. If we keep answering follow up questions in the comments section, it will be a never-ending thread. Cheers!

it is same question actually, because in the thread I have VALUES("user1"),("user2"),("user3"), these represent the list that I am talking about.
